# Recursive way of Binary Search with nested function in Python

Tags: python, recursion, nested, binary-search

I implemented a recursive way of binary search and I'm facing a problem. 
Ths is my code:

```
def foo(x, ls):
    left, right = 0, len(ls)-1
    def search(l, r):
        if l>r:
            return False
        mid = (l+r)//2
        if x < ls[mid]:
            return search(l,mid-1)
        elif x > ls[mid]:
            return search(mid+1,r)
        else:
            return True

    return search(left,right)
```

this function works fine. However if I remove the `return` from the if statements, and call search function without a `return`, it raises wrong answers. Can anyone explain this? What is the exact difference?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. You created a code that works, and you wonder why breaking it doesn't work?

Comment: No, i dont wanna break it. I just asking the diference between recursing with return statement and without.

Comment: Because without `return` you're running the same code but the calculation being done just disappears when it's done. `return` does just that, it returns the result you worked hard to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't return a value in a recursive function, the [tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) of this function is just returning None, which is evaluated to False if you try to convert it to boolean value